# not able to connect mongoDB with Codeigniter4 due to mongoDB php driver not installed

Tags: php, database, mongodb, codeigniter

When trying to install the MongoDB PHP driver getting this error.

[image]

I already enabled:

`extension=php_openssl.dll` in the php.ini file

Comment: please check https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-and-codeigniter

Comment: i already checked this article.
i only stuck in this command => pecl install mongodb

Comment: Perhaps you need OpenSSL installed? https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries